# Compare populations behaviour according to a single variable

Tags: time-series, survival, multiple-comparisons

Let's say that I study three populations that are divided according to a single variable all I have is the three plots of their behaviour with in the x-axis a linear timeline and in the "y-axis" some ratio which i'm studying.

Basically, this is kind of similar to a survival anaysis except that i can't use the usual models because I'm not studying the ratio of survivors, i have the data to do that but instead I study the ratio of days that are lived after the x-th day.

(For instance if i have only 2 individuals one that lasted 2 days and the other one that lasted 8 days, and i'm looking at the 5-th day on my graph i will put (8-5)/(2+8)=3/10)

I want to know if the 3 populations have statistically speaking a real difference in their behaviour (Is there any type of commonly used condition to tell wether a difference is significant or not ?). What is the method to do so?

To make it as clear and as simple as possible :

I'm in a internship, i have this plot which is about sick leaves, the percentages i'm refering to are the one i tried to explain before, those two plots represent my whole population divided on whether or not they have a specific type of contract:

[image]

I've been asked to determine wether there is 'a statistical diffrence' between those two populations, if there is I need to make two tables if there isn't I make one.(By the way i don't even know if this request makes any sense since I know almost nothing about statistics, so if it's completely absurd just tell me it isn't feasible to answer this question) I'm supposed to divide my population by considering many variables, the type of contract is one of them.

If u want to know what the data looks like, it's a dataframe, with on each line a single sick leave with various variables describing it, including its duration in days.

So I just want to know is there a basic(or not) way to tell if there is a statistical difference ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Please supply more details: what kind of "real difference"?  How was this "some ratio" measured?  Are the times chosen at regular intervals, making this a [tag:time-series] question, or are they random, or just irregular?

Comment: Although your English looks fine, the description of your data is hard to follow.  Would you be able to post a small, concrete example of the data and the plots to help people understand?

Comment: Okay , I tried another approach if this looks more clear to you i'll completely remove the first part and edit the second so that it has all the useful informations.